# Audio file copied from raw to sd but cannot be played

Tags: file, audio, copy, sd-card

I want to create an android aplication which can copies some audio files from the raw folder of the Eclipse project to the sd card. The files are copied to the sd card but the media player cannot be played with the next message "The player does not support this type of audio file", it seems that the file is corrupted but i don't know the reason. This is my code:

```
Button copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {

            File sdCard, directory = null;
            String nombreMP3 = "audio.mp3";
            BufferedInputStream  entrada = null;
            BufferedOutputStream salida = null;
            int len=0;
            sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            directory = new File( sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/CarpetaAplicacion2");
            if (!directory.exists()){
                directory.mkdir();
            }
            File f = new File(directory, nombreMP3);
            try {                   
                entrada = new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dignidad));
                salida = new BufferedOutputStream((new FileOutputStream(f)),4096);
                byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
            while ((len=entrada.read()) > 0){   
                synchronized (buff){
                    salida.write(buff,0,len);
                    salida.flush();}
            }

            } catch (IOException ex) { 
                if( entrada != null){
                    try {
                        entrada.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}
                if (salida != null) {
              try {
                salida.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
            }
            finally{
                if( entrada != null){
                    try {
                        entrada.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}
                if (salida != null) {
              try {
                salida.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```